# RestyGWT: does it support plain text?

Tags: gwt, resty-gwt

I'm not able to receive plain text using RestyGWT. A very simple test service looks like this:

```
@GET
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
void test(MethodCallback<String> callback);
```

On the client side I always get:

```
Response was NOT a valid JSON document
```

Looking at the HTTP response I'm seeing that content type is set correctly:

```
Content-Type:text/plain
```

What's the problem? Why RestyGWT tries to parse this as JSON? Am I doing smth wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, RestyGWT is a Json library, AFAIK it is not made to handle plain text, or XML, or anything else. `"foo"` isn't a valid Json data, should be `["foo"]` or `{"stuff": "foo"}`.

Indeed, in our Rest API, we tried to send pure text (an id), but we finally made a simple object wrapping the id.

Answer (score 4):

If you will use `TextCallback` instead of `MethodCallback<String>` you won't get this error.
It will set `Accept` header automatically to `text/plain`, so you don't have to use `@Produces` adnotation in your async interface.

Comment: For the record, this is explained at the [official documentation](https://resty-gwt.github.io/documentation/restygwt-user-guide.html) (under REST API), but not in the javadocs. Oddly enough, `TextCallback` extends `MethodCallback<String>`.